# How to get notification from Azure Sql database on insert

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I need to get a notification or call a webservice whenever a row is inserted into a specific table in my Azure Sql Database. I have been searching the web for a good solution, but i haven't found any.

I tried to call a web app service in Azure - but this is not allowed from Azure Sql Databases.
I looked at the Azure logic apps, but the SQL Server Connector has been removed.

How do I get notificated when a row is put in?

Comment: This is not possible in SQLAzure,one option might be to poll the table as per desired time frames

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
Is this really impossible, there must be some other way of doing this?
I need to publish data on-demand and quick - so polling data will produce a overload of calls to the sql server.

Comment: May be you need an Azure Function which will be doing two things: 1) insert row into Azure Sql Database 2) call a webservice ?

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not natively supported in SQL Azure, there are a few different options you can consider.

1) Modify the calling code to insert a row into the table and write a message to Azure storage queue. You can have a separate process which drains the message from the queue and invokes the web service so that these actions are loosely coupled.

2) Enable change tracking on the specific table so that your app can discover the latest changes (i.e. inserts) to the table. This feature is well documented if you search the Azure SQL docs.